# Error:Some file crunching failed on new project

Tags: java, android, gradle

I get one of the following errors when I create a new project:

Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
```

I tried to clean and rebuild the projects several times, but it didn't work.

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.andrei.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Could you post your log cat?

Comment: can you paste your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes, i posted it. It's just a new project, I haven't added anything to it.